# Using R function curve when function output is a list

Tags: r, function, plot

I am familiar with plotting functions in R with the function`curve` when the output of the function is a simple expression (such as a single number). How do we deal with functions who's outputs are a bit more complicated, such as lists?

An example to make myself clear. Suppose I have the following function.

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d){
    check <- a
    prob <- c:d
    n <- c*2
    r <- d-b
    lista <- list(check,prob,n,r)
    names(lista) <- c("check", "prob", "n", "r")
    return(lista)
}

f <- Vectorize(f, vectorize.args = "a")
```

How would one go about using the function`curve` to plot the result of one of the elements of the output list, say`n`, as a function of`a`? This works very smoothly if I set the return to only`n`, but what if I want to keep the current list output for other purposes?

I have checked `?curve`, and it states, rather depressingly, that

> For expensive-to-compute expressions, you should use smarter tools

Don't think this is a case where this applies, but indeed, as the help page has suggested, "the way`curve` handles`expr`has caused confusion".

A naive approach would be to call

```
curve(f(x, b= 2, c= 3, d=1)$n)
```

but this doesn't seem to do the job. Any solution in sight without having to change the function output or having to use "ggplot" and the sort?

Comment: Is there any reason you just don't use `plot`? `curve` is just a wrapper of `plot`, so don't see a reason why one should stick with `curve`. For instance, just a simple `plot(x,f(x, b= 2, c= 3, d=1)$n,ty="l")` will get you close to the plot obtained with `curve`.

Comment: @nicola I would like to do it without having to specify a vector of possible values to pass to the function. The example I have provided is a dummy; the real function I'm using is way more complicated. It is a step function and I have no idea where it jumps. Plus, I'd love to uncover the misteries of `curve`

Comment: `curve()` takes what it takes parameter-wise. I'd love it if ggplot2 took raw JSON and made magical plots for me w/o specifying `geom`s but that's not going to happen. `curve` has `0` mysteries. Type `curve` at an R console, hit Enter. Your question is not complete since you never gave us a vector for `x`.

Comment: @Easymode44 Read the doc to see how the points are calculated. They are just `seq(from,to,length.out=n)`, where `from`, `to` and `n` are the parameters you pass to `curve`. If you don't pass those values, `from=0`, `to=1` and `n=101` (unless you are plotting over existing plots). So just use `plot`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I will follow your suggestion and read`curve` in depth (although I was hoping for a more in-depth hint from Stackoverflow - care to elaborate on "parameter-wise"). And I need not specify `x`. If you change the return in the function to `return(n)`, I can use `curve` smoothly, with `x` as abscissa.

Comment: @nicola Grazie. I'll go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the extraction of the element before vectorizing.  That is,

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d){
    check <- a
    prob <- c:d
    n <- c*2
    r <- d-b
    lista <- list(check,prob,n,r)
    names(lista) <- c("check", "prob", "n", "r")
    return(lista)
}
fn <- Vectorize(function(x) f(x, b= 2, c= 3, d=1)$n)
curve(fn)
```

If you really want to use the original vectorized version of `f`, then you need to realize that the result depends on the result of your function, and is not simply a dataframe or list.  In your case it's a list-mode matrix with 4 rows.  So you could use

```
f <- function(a,b,c,d){
    check <- a
    prob <- c:d
    n <- c*2
    r <- d-b
    lista <- list(check,prob,n,r)
    names(lista) <- c("check", "prob", "n", "r")
    return(lista)
}

f <- Vectorize(f, vectorize.args = "a")

curve((function(a) unlist(f(a, b=2, c=3, d=1)["n",]))(x))
```

or

```
fn <- function(a) unlist(f(a, b=2, c=3, d=1)["n",])

curve(fn)
```

(and there are probably other expressions that would work), but is it really worth figuring this out?

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, for you answer. I guess it was worth it to the extent I really got a grasp on how `curve` works.